# Open .NET Core 2.0 dump in lldb on Linux - which lldb version?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, .net-core, lldb

I'm trying to open a .NET Core 2.0 dump on Ubuntu 16.04, following instructions from http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2017/02/26/analyzing-a-net-core-core-dump-on-linux/

Dump is created from running process with `createdump PID`.

I can not determine correct version of lldb.
`ldd $(find /usr/share/dotnet -name libsosplugin.so) | grep lldb` does not return anything (there is no lldb in the output).

I have tried latest, 3.5 and 3.6, to no avail:
`Can not load or initialize libmscordaccore.so. The target runtime may not be initialized.`

How can I find a correct lldb version for .NET Core 2.0 dumps?

---

**Update: commands with output**

`$ find /usr/share/dotnet -name libsosplugin.so
/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.0.5/libsosplugin.so`

`$ ldd $(find /usr/share/dotnet -name libsosplugin.so)
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffca344f000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f3d7eecc000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3d7ebc3000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f3d7e9ad000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3d7e5e3000)`

Comment: Check commands individually and post their outputs `find /usr/share/dotnet -name libsosplugin.so` and then `ldd $(find /usr/share/dotnet -name libsosplugin.so)`

Comment: @TarunLalwani added to the question

Comment: See if this https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/13937 or https://github.com/mikem8361/coreclr/blob/5c22cb85c7cc9173f2fb783bf24c0cbbb6096c89/Documentation/building/debugging-instructions.md helps

Comment: As stated, I have already tried all of that. Linked article uses lldb-3.6, which does not work for me.

Comment: Can you try customizing the dotnet docker image and install lldb inside and try and see if it helps? So basically the same environment where you actually took the dump

Answer (score 0):

Quite old question, but maybe this helps someone:

E.g. Dockerfile to include lldb and into asp dotnet 3.1

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1

WORKDIR /vsdbg
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        unzip \
        procps \
        lldb-3.9 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | bash /dev/stdin -v vs2019 -l /vsdbg
WORKDIR /app
```

Also at a look at this site: https://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2019-04-04-debugging-dotnet-in-docker-with-vscode/

And add CAP_SYS_PTRACE at docker run if you want to attach to the running process inside container.